# Live Wallpaper on lockscreen for different models

Tags: android

So I have a live wallpaper app published. I know different lockscreen wallpapers are not AOSP but rather a feature for each OEM, but many of my users use those modified ROMs from the OEMS and I get tons of requests/bad reviews from users about how to set it for the lockscreen because they dont know they can do that from the settings.

Some time ago I found that for most Samsung devices you can make the live wallpaper preview set the live wallpaper for the lockscreen too by specifying this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(this, LiveWallpaperService.class));
intent.putExtra("SET_LOCKSCREEN_WALLPAPER", true);
```

I was wondering if other OEMS such as LG/Sony/etc have also intent parameters to do this.

Comment: I feel your pain! :(